# Why is "reduce" an infix operator in Chapel?

Tags: reduction, chapel

According to this [manual](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/reductions.html) page, we can use `reduce` to perform reduction like
summation (+):

```
var a = (+ reduce A) / num;
var b = + reduce abs(A);
var c = sqrt(+ reduce A**2);
```

and maximum value/location:

```
var (maxVal, maxLoc) = maxloc reduce zip(A, A.domain);
```

Here, Chapel defines `reduce` to be an infix operator rather than a function (e.g., `reduce( A, + )`). IMHO, the latter form seems to be a bit more readable because the arguments are always separated by parentheses. So I am wondering if there is some reason for this choice (e.g., to simplify some parallel syntax) or just a matter of history (convention)?

Comment: Note that this issue https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/11463 is related.

Comment: Thanks! I will check the conversation there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the answer is a matter of history / convention.  A lot of Chapel's array and domain features were heavily inspired by the ZPL language from the University of Washington, and I believe this syntax was taken reasonably directly from ZPL.

At the time, we didn't have a notion of passing things like functions and operators around in Chapel, which is probably one of the reasons that we didn't consider more of a function-based approach.  (Even now, first-class function support in Chapel is still somewhat in its infancy, and I don't believe we have a way to pass operators around).

I'd also say that Chapel is a language that generally favors syntax for key patterns rather than taking more of a "make everything look like a function / method call" approach (e.g., ranges are supported via a literal syntax and several key operators rather than using an object type with methods).

None of this is to say that the choice was obviously right or couldn't be reconsidered.

Comment: [Thanks, my rep points are too low to add +1, so will do it later :)]

Comment: One other minor note:  I personally tend think of `reduce` as a prefix unary operator (one that is itself prefixed by the type of reduction to compute) rather than an infix/binary operator.  But that's probably splitting hairs.  Technically it is infix, coming between two other expressions.